# Modifying VLAN attachments

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-interconnect

[https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/interconnect/how-to/dedicated/modifying-vlan-attachments#console]

Docs indicate you can increase VLAN attachment bandwidth in the console but that option is not available to me. There is no capacity field as you can hopefully see in the included image.

[Missing capacity field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZK25.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it (Capacity: The maximum bandwidth of the attachment) by using gcloud command:

```
gcloud compute interconnects attachments dedicated update NAME \
    --region=REGION \
    --description=DESCRIPTION \
    --bandwidth=BANDWIDTH \
    --mtu MTU
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm just now going to implement this but I need it for a partner attachment and the bandwidth flag is not present although it is for a dedicated vlan attachment. It doesn't appear to be available under the alpha/beta command set either.